# Moving connections and instances between two computers

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I´ve got a mysql-server that I´m administrate remotely with MySQL Workbench.

Now I´ve got a new computer and I cant find any solution to move my connections and instances-profiles to my new computer. This can´t be an unsolved question, huh? Not the first time this would happen for someone else.

Correction: It´s not the server-instances that I want to move. I need to export/move/backup my many client-profiles/instances-connections in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I had the same questions. I found a MySQL directory in %APPDATA%. Copy the entire directory to the same location on the new machine. You'll need clear your passwords and re-enter them. Once I did that, I was up and running again.

You can find your %APPDATA% folder in Windows by entering it in the address bar of Windows Explorer.

Comment: You won't need the whole file, just connections.xml.  You'll still need to enter in the passwords again for each connection.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to re-enter passwords anymore in version 6.0.8, awesome!

Comment: Windows 7 Location:  C:\Users\[user-name]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh

Comment: On Linux the configuration are in ~/.mysql/workbench/

Comment: @DrCord apparently, in 6.3 need for re-entering password comes back.

Comment: Super lame they made you have to reenter passwords, this makes me not want to ever upgrade again, my work copy of MySQL workbench has so many passwords saved...

Comment: Thanks. Didn't even need to retype the passwords.

Answer (score 135):

You don't need to copy any files manually as other answers suggest. On both Windows and Mac  you can export all your settings within MySQL Workbench and restore to another system.

```
Select Tools > Configuration > Backup Connections
```

This will export as a .zip. Then on your new new install just

```
Select Tools > Configuration > Restore Connections
```

[image: Linux MySQL Workbench Backup/Restore Connections]

That's it!

Comment: @ Spaceships , @Glyn Jackson  hi, I wander that how to execute the command in the windows.Thanks

Comment: sadly, it does not backup your passwords

Comment: What I got by trying this: Error during "Restore connections from a backup file". error calling Python module function PyWbUtils.restoreConnections

Comment: @Vlado i have the same problem, Workbench version 8.0.25

Comment: @Vlado Same issue. Looks like its been a bug since Feb 2021

Comment: Bug here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103579

Comment: I had the same problem while migrating from Windows to Windows and I managed to work around the Python error. Here is what I did: Downgraded the workbench on both source and target computers to 8.0.12. Created a backup zip on the source computer, restored it on the target computer, and then updated the workbench on target to the latest.

Answer (score 15):

Found it on a mac in 
/Users/Username/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/

file called connections.xml

Comment: Thanks! I was able to copy the connections.xml and server_instances.xml from a PC to a Mac, and all my connections from the PC were then available on my Mac.

Comment: On Mac OS X High Sierra & MysqlWorkbench 6.3, the file ~/Library//Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/connections.xml is empty.

Answer (score 13):

Backup and restore connections using the menus **Tools > Configuration > Backup Connections** and **Tools > Configuration > Restore Connections** is the easiest way, however it does not copy the passwords.

**Extracting the passwords is possible in the following case:**

1. **Old PC** should be a Windows installation.
2. You should be able to login using the Windows account who originally saved the passwords in  Workbench, i.e. without having the Windows account's password reset by an admin.

If the above requirements are met, one can log into the old PC and run the decrypt tool found on http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=41860.msg391762#msg391762

The C++ code to decrypt is shown below (credits: f0dder)

```
std::vector<unsigned char> decrypt(BYTE *input, size_t length) {
        DATA_BLOB inblob { length, input };
        DATA_BLOB outblob;

        if (!CryptUnprotectData(&inblob, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN, &outblob)) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't decrypt");
        }

        std::vector<unsigned char> output(length);
        memcpy(&output[0], outblob.pbData, outblob.cbData);

        return output;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Linux (Ubuntu), the location was changed to `$HOME/.mysql/workbench`

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Verified on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: For me it was `gedit ~/snap/mysql-workbench-community/current/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml` on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 7):

Before replacing the connection.xml, make sure you close the Workbench application first, or the application will overwrite/save on the xml file on exit.

Comment: heh glad you wrote it :)

Answer (score 4):

just copy them!

in Linux, they're at `$HOME/.mysqlgui/`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to recover the passwords that are encrypted in "workbench_user_data.dat" file using Python in Windows, you can use the below snippet.

```
import os,win32crypt
encrypted_data = open(f"C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\AppData\\Roaming\\MySQL\\Workbench\\workbench_user_data.dat", "rb").read()
clear_data = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_data, None, None, None, 0)
print(clear_data)
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing and why it answers the question

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, on the latest version of the MySQL Workbench (8.0.25, 8.0.27 in windows at least), the backup and restore for .zip file formats does NOT work.

See here for details and a workaround:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102501

Answer (score 1):

With C# on .NET Framework 4.x on Windows, or with .NET Core - or .NET 5 or later using [the Windows Compatibility Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack), just copy and paste this into a new console project:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String appDataRoaming = Environment.GetFolderPath( System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData );
    //  String appDataRoaming = @"C:\Users\$you\AppData\Roaming\";

        FileInfo workbenchUserDataFileName = new FileInfo( Path.Combine( appDataRoaming, @"MySQL\Workbench\workbench_user_data.dat" ) );

        Byte[] ciphertext = File.ReadAllBytes( path: workbenchUserDataFileName.FullName );
        Byte[] cleartext  = ProtectedData.Unprotect( ciphertext, optionalEntropy: null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser );
        
        String text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString( cleartext ); // <-- You may need to change this to `Encoding.UTF8`
        text = text.Replace( '\u0002', '\n' ).Replace( '\u0003', '\n' );
        Console.WriteLine( text );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the file "WbProfiles.xml" in path C:\Users\.sqlworkbench\WbProfiles.xml

Either copy the file or copy complete ".sqlworkbench" folder under same path in new machine.

Answer (score 0):

BACKUP work-around for this bug:

- copy these two files: connections.xml and server_instances.xml
- location of these files (in windows) is: C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench   (replace  with your own windows username)

To RESTORE:
copy those above 2 files to the same location on the destination installation.

caveat: I don't know where the password "vault" is kept for the connections, so you may have to re-enter those, but the connections and server list are preserved.

Bonus: to restore your workspaces (all open .sql tabs, etc.) you can also copy the "sql_workspaces" directory underneath the "workbench" directory and it will restore those too!