# How can I backup MySQL Connections on MySQLWorkBench?

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, macos-mojave, database-connection

I've been using MySQL WorkBench for so long on Mac OS X. 
I've been trying to **save/backup** all my host connections before I update MySQL WorkBench.

[image]

**Is there a way to do that ?**

Comment: What do you mean by backing up connections? You normally backup data. In any case, this probably belongs on [dba.se], it doesn't seem like a programming question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving connections and instances between two computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450880/moving-connections-and-instances-between-two-computers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Mac, find the file `~/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/connections.xml`

This XML file contains all the connection info, except for plaintext passwords (those are stored in the Keychain).

---

Re your comment:

I don't know why you need to delete the app. Just install the latest version over the old version. That's what I do, and what I assume everyone else does too.

You would not need to back up the connections.xml file unless you want to install MySQL Workbench on a different Macbook, and bring the connections to that new installation. But you'd need to enter the passwords again anyway.

Comment: So if we delete the app, and download the latest version, all our hosts connections should be auto restore for us magically ? yes ?

Comment: Thank-you very much for your precise answer. It clears a lot of my doubts.

Answer (score 6):

To backup/restore connections you can use 'Backup Connections...'/'Restore Connections...' form Tools->Configuration menu.

[image]

Comment: should be the accepted answer!